# Can we call Restful WCF Service from SSIS Package

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, ssis

I have an SSIS Package from which i need to call a WCF Serive which is exposed as REST.
Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to learn about [How to configure SSIS Package to accss a wcf service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that, but the example shows how to use WCF using script task transaformation as a Source/Transform/Destination but i need to call a WCF service from SSIS package using "Call WebService Task"

Comment: WebService task requires an asmx or wsdl which does not exist for REST. So you have to scipt the interface by yourself.